# Stop specific range from refreshing

Tags: excel, refresh, bloomberg, vba

I am using a web plugin (Bloomberg) and have a specific range in a macro that needs to be recalculated. However, it is important that another range does not recalculate (the Bloomberg web plug-in) because it slows down the PC so much. Just stopping overall calculation during the macro is not sufficient, it really needs to be tied to a specific range or sheet.

Here is my code so far, which does not work:

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect
Range("M1:CV1556").Locked = False
Range("A13:K1556").Locked = True
ActiveSheet.Protect
```

Following solutions could be possible: Disabling all web plugins and thus prevent new data being download, which is the reason for the slow code. However, I do not know how to do that in VBA.

Comment: Locked  only affect a cell while the protection is activated they have nothing to do with refreshing. an unlocked cell will be modifiable even if the sheet is protected while a locked cell won't. Formulas still execute. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff836172.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example that will show which AddIns are available, and then how to disable them. You can probably use this to disable the add-in prior to performing an update on another range.

```
Public Sub Addin_Test()
    Dim myRow       As Long
    Dim objCOMAddin As Object

    'Finding Add-Ins, adding to ActiveSheet
    lngRow = 1
    With ActiveSheet
        For Each objCOMAddin In Application.COMAddIns
            .Cells(lngRow, "A").Value = objCOMAddin.Description
            .Cells(lngRow, "B").Value = objCOMAddin.Connect
            .Cells(lngRow, "C").Value = objCOMAddin.progID
            lngRow = lngRow + 1
        Next objCOMAddin
    End With

    'How to disable an Add in?
    Application.COMAddIns("Addin ProgID Goes here").Connect = False
End Sub
```